# Is it feasible to do a Monopoly board pub crawl in London?

Tags: uk, london, food-and-drink, alcohol

Putting aside the question of how intoxicated one might become, is it feasible to travel to all the "streets" on a Monopoly board in London in a single day?  How long would it take?  Do all these places exist or would substitutions need to be made?

This list of streets is:

- Old Kent Road
- Whitechapel Road
- Kings Cross Station
- The Angel Islington
- Euston Road
- Pentonville Road
- Pall Mall
- Electric Company
- Whitehall
- Northumberland Avenue
- Marylebone Station
- Bow Street
- Marlborough Street
- Vine Street
- The Strand
- Fleet Street
- Trafalgar Square
- Fenchurch St Station
- Leicester Square
- Coventry Street
- Water Works
- Piccadilly
- Regent Street
- Oxford Street
- Bond Street
- Liverpool Street Station
- Park Lane
- Mayfair

Comment: I didn't realize the Monopoly board had different street names across the pond... where can I buy one of these online? :)

Comment: @Flimzy they're different in each country, with locations specific to that country. In the Netherlands e.g. there's streets in different cities (Amsterdam, Rotterdam, Utrecht, and others), not just different streets in a single city.

Comment: @jwenting: That's not true of the two versions I'm familiar with: The U.S. and Mexican versions.  The Mexican version just uses Spanish translations of the names from the U.S. game... Thus my "surprise."

Comment: Growing up in Australia we had a London based board (as above), with pounds instead of dollars.  There is an Australian board as well; now *that* would be some pub-crawl.

Comment: @Flimzy I'd guess the "Mexican version" was merely a translated US version aimed at Hispanics in the US but also sold across the border.

Comment: @jwenting: Very possible. (Board games aren't very common in Mexico anyway, so making a dedicated "Mexican" version likely wouldn't be very cost effective.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is indeed possible in theory, and VERY difficult in practice.  You need to start, traditionally, at Elephant and Castle at 10am.  Going at about 20-30 min per pub you will just finish before closing in Central London.  It's hard, really hard, and you need someone to keep tabs on the time and keep everyone moving.

[There's a webpage](http://monopolypubcrawl.org.uk/) with strategies, maps and suggestions which can help you in your quest. [Example map of their "original route" (pin colours based on actual Monopoly board colours):](http://monopolypubcrawl.org.uk/map/original/)

[image]

Comment: As I recall some of the streets no longer exist such as bow street so you have to settle for new bow street. In saying that I did consume 13 pints that and my memory is sketchy from about the second food stop onwards.

Comment: At least you skipped Gaol.

Comment: @WW. Curiously enough how this is the last stop for many people in their pub crawl.

Comment: @Stuart Food stop?! Eating's for wimps, Rodney ;-)

Answer (score 7):

When I was a kid we visited every street on the Monopoly board as a sponsored event. We didn't drink at each (we were underage), but visiting is certainly feasible. We even managed to include the Utilities (HQ of the electric and water companies) and a prison (Pentonville - the stop that added most to our time).

Comment: prison is designed for long term stay :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are strict about it, it is not possible because I think none of the four stations have actually pubs in them (while Waterloo station does). There are pubs nearby but they are on different streets.

I would also say that 'Trafalgar Square' itself has no pub either.

Also what to do with 'Electric Company' and 'Water Works'?

On the other hand, 'Bow street' still exists and has pubs.

Comment: Agreed, we had to do pubs close to Fenchurch station etc.  Many people actually leave off the stations just to make it a bit easier time-wise, but it's a better challenge to do them ;)

Comment: When I did it some years ago, Marylebone station had a pub.

Comment: Kings Cross has a pub (the Parcel Yard).