# Pub crawl of central London

Tags: london, alcohol

I would like to organize a pub crawl of central London – zone 1.

- Minimum 6 pubs, preferably 8
- located close to each other; a strong preference for walking, although I could live with one cab trip between two areas
- historic pubs would be nice; certainly “olde” looking
- not J.D Wetherspoon type chain pubs, which are more restaurant than bar
- preferably real boozers; locals rather than tourist places

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Porcupine, 48 Charing Cross Road
- The Crown, 51 New Oxford Street
- The Edgar Wallace, 40 Essex Street (my favorite!)
- The Swan, 7 Cosmo Place
- The Grapes, 14 Lime Street (there is another lovely pub with the same name at Narrow Street but that's not zone 1 anymore)
- The Cock & Woolpack, 6 Finch Lane
- Ye Old Mitre, 1 Ely court
- The Blackfriar, 174 Queen Victoria Street

... and many more

[image]

Comment: Excellent (+1). But you would really improve it by giving street names for all (plus a few more pubs ;-)  If I had spare time, I would also give the walking time or distance between each :-)

Comment: "I would also give the walking time or distance between each" well, google is your friend ;-)

Comment: Yes, but since you are new here, you might not have considered that you are not just answering me, but everyone who read this question in future. Should Google be all of their friends? No offence intended here; this is a good answer and I will certainly accept it if nothing better comes along. But it seems like you have a very good local knowledge and could turn a god answer into an excellent – and well upvoted - answer. You don’t need to, of course. In any case, welcome aboard and thanks for the help

Comment: I get your point but a little self-initiative is never wrong.

Comment: But a little self imitative by everyone who reads your answer becomes a lot of self-imitative :-)

Comment: I added a map of the crawl, which is pretty long (4.3 miles, 1h30 after reordering the pubs a bit)

Comment: Edit: I had to change the map since I put in the wrong adress for The Crown (appologies!). Note: The Crown can also be entered throught the back entrance on Shaftsbury Avenue.

Comment: @Mawg Since you _aren't_ new here, you should know that we don't do this kind of question, here. Teaching Nicolas how to answer off-topic questions isn't really helpful.

Comment: We don't?? Then I wonder how [Is it feasible to do a Monopoly board pub crawl in London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/is-it-feasible-to-do-a-monopoly-board-pub-crawl-in-london) got 17 up-votes. And apparently I dreamed [Where is Dublin's (Ireland) city center and most ideal location for nightlife/pubs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17247/where-is-dublins-ireland-city-center-and-most-ideal-location-for-nightlife-pu/17248#17248)

Comment: Also, I don't see anything wrong - on any of our sites - in saying "that is a good answer, and I will accept it, but if you add more detail your answer will help more people and get more up-votes". YKmMV (your kilometrage may vary ;-)

Comment: -100 for not mentioning the old bank of England on Fleet st or the Cheshire Cheese down the road. Unforgivable.